# inject runtime exception nutch 2.3

Tags: nutch

I get stuck with setup Nutch 2.3 with hbase 0.94:

```
fx@fx:~$ $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject file:///home/fx/Abivin/apache-nutch-2.3/seed/urls.txt
InjectorJob: starting at 2015-06-17 14:46:35
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: file:/home/fx/Abivin/apache-nutch-2.3/seed/urls.txt
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=inject file:/home/fx/Abivin/apache-nutch-2.3/seed/urls.txt, jobid=job_local1999341506_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:231)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

when seed/urls.txt stores urls. I've searched many similar errors but still get stuck with this. Please give me some ideas to resolve. Thanks

Comment: Could you add the code or command you used that generated this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Nutch cannot inject URL to 'webpage' table. First, please check the configuration in gora-hbase. In the case the configuration is correct, you should delete the hbase data directory and start again.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Le, I've followed your crawling posts. I have many things to resolve with nutch because I am actually a new in this field. Could we share contact? my email is dongnt@abivin.com. Thank you so much :)